# Save item array with specific keys

Tags: php, arrays

How to save specific items from array using array keys.

**INPUT:**

```
$arr = [
    0 => 'item0',
    2 => 'item2',
    4 => 'item4',
    43 => 'item43'
];
```

Now I only want to save keys **2** and **43**.

**Expected Output:**

```
$arr = [
   2 => 'item2',
   43 => 'item43'
];
```

**Current Code:**

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   if(!($key == 2 || $key == 43)) {
       unset($arr[$key]);
   }
}
```

It works for now, but what if i have more array keys to save.

Comment: Check out [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one. Here we are using [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

> `array_intersect_key` Computes the intersection of arrays using keys.
>
> `array_flip` will flip array over keys and values.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/875025)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$arr = [
    0 => 'item0',
    2 => 'item2',
    4 => 'item4',
    43 => 'item43'
];

$keys= [
    2,
    43
];
$result=array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($keys));
print_r($result);
```

**Solution** for current code try [here](https://eval.in/875029).

You should use `!=` and with `&&` instead of `||`

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) 
{
   if($key != 2 && $key != 43) 
   {
       unset($arr[$key]);
   }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for. Thanks

Comment: @just_a_simple_guy Glad to help you friend... :)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
        <?PHP
    $mykeys=array(2,5,9,7,3,4);

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
       if(!(in_array($key,$mykeys) {
           unset($arr[$key]);
       }
    }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put the keys you want to keep in an array then iterate over it like this:

```
$keys = array(); // put the keys here
foreach ( $arr as $key => $value) {
  $found = 0;
  foreach($keys as $filterKey) {
    if ($key == $filterKey) {
      $found = 1;
      break;
    }
    $found = 0;
  }
  if ($found == 0) {
    unset($arr[$key]);
  }
}
```